# Undeclared variables become property of global object. But why does accessing it via WINDOW.variable slows down performance

Tags: javascript, v8

While trying few benchmark scenarios for accessing a variable found that "**accessing undeclared variables**" is faster when compared to **"accessing undeclared variables using window object**"

When a variable is undeclared, it becomes a property of window object. Okay, why not try to access it using the window object? doing so gave bad performance timings. Please refer to **3** below

[image: Variable Access - Benchmark]

Comment: It can give an idea even though the solution is exactly the same. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31068060/why-is-accessing-a-variable-using-window-variable-slower

Comment: Just to add one more scenario, `(function(){
console.time("loop");
for( let i = 0; i<100000; i++){
}
console.timeEnd("loop");
})()`