# What is the difference between window.console.log and console.log

Tags: javascript, console.log

Just went through an interview. The first question asked me was what is `console.log()`. I answered with so confidence. Again,

The second question was, what is the difference between `window.console.log()` and `console.log()`. I was speechless. Tried searching in Google and Stack Overflow. I didn't find such helpful post to understand the difference between them.

Any thoughts is greatly appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Console

Comment: in a browser page, they'd typically be identical since `window` is the global namespace. not necessarily in other contexts.

Comment: That sounds good. So by function and output there is no difference at all ?  Did the interviewer tried to trick me ?

Comment: Not being a mind reader, it's hard to know what the interviewer was trying to do, but my guess would be that the question was to test your awareness of `window` being the global object (at least in some environments).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should one write window.X when referring to a built-in global property X in the browser?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5460593/1048572)

Comment: see also [Why is accessing a variable using window.variable slower?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31068060/1048572)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Should one write window.X when referring to a built-in global property X in the (desktop) browser?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5460593/should-one-write-window-x-when-referring-to-a-built-in-global-property-x-in-the)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

In a normal browser context, there is no difference. `console` is a global variable, and all globals are properties of the `window` object.

```js
console.log(console.log==window.console.log) // true
```

There are some caveats, such as when not running in the browser, or if the console variable has been reassigned. [T.J. Crowder](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41450093/3187556) explains it nicely.

Comment: There is a difference, it just isn't usually significant.

Comment: It won't be `true` in workers and other contexts where `window` is not the global object.

Comment: (And as of ES2015, not all globals are properties of the global object.)

Comment: @TedHopp "In the browser", and workers don't run in a normal browser context.

Comment: @Scimonster: Web workers absolutely are "in the browser." (Yes, it is a different environment from the default one.)

Comment: The question OP faced didn't seem to specify that it was "in the browser", so your answer seems incomplete.

Comment: @TedHopp: :-) Oh, I wouldn't give Sci a hard time about that, I bet you that's what the OP meant.

Comment: Short and sweet answer with a nice example. Thanks

Answer (score 36):

If you mean in the default browser JavaScript environment, there is effectively none *provided* `window` and `console` haven't been shadowed or reassigned.

In the default browser JavaScript environment, `window` is a global that refers to the global object, which is also the window object. The global object holds most globals as properties (it used to be all, but in ES2015 that changed; globals created by `let`, `const`, or `class` are not properties of the global object). But that's not true in most non-browser environments (NodeJS, for instance, uses `global` instead of `window`), or even in some non-default browser environments (such as a web worker's environment, which doesn't have `window` as they can't access the window). So in environments where `window` isn't defined, `window.console.log` will fail where `console.log` wouldn't (provided the environment provides a global `console`).

To understand the difference, let's work each of them through:

`console.log(...)` means:

1. The JavaScript engine has to search for the a binding for the identifier `console` starting with the current execution context, then the next one, then the next, until it finds it at global scope.
2. Then it looks up the `log` property on the resulting object.
3. Then it calls it

`window.console.log(...)` means:

1. The JavaScript engine has to search for the a binding for the identifier `window` starting with the current execution context, then the next one, then the next, until it finds it at global scope.
2. Then it looks up the `console` property on the resulting object.
3. Then it looks up the `log` property on the resulting object.
4. Then it calls it

So for instance, here's an example where `console` has been shadowed, and so `console.log` fails whereas `window.console.log` works:

```js
function foo() {
  var console = 42;
  
  try {
    console.log("You WON'T see this.");
  } catch (e) {
  }

  try {
    window.console.log("You WILL see this.");
  } catch (e) {
  }
}
foo();
```

Comment: also provided you're running in a browser page which is not a given.

Comment: @pvg: Quite, I just re-read the question, and it doesn't actually say that. :-)

Comment: @Santosh: I don't know what you mean by "priority."

Comment: @Santosh - `window.console.log()` restricts your code to work in environments where `window` is the global object (or a property of the global object). I'd use `console.log()` (without the `window.` prefix) because that will work anywhere that `console` is defined in the global object, whatever it is named.

Comment: @pvg: Thanks to you and Ted, I've addressed the non-browser and web worker aspects now, which I'd just completely glossed over... :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah. I think it's deliberate (not by the author) so as to fall nicely into the category of 'crappy interview questions'.

Comment: @pvg: Whether purposefully or not, it does fall into that category. ;-)

Comment: @pvg, I disagree that it is inherently a crappy interview question. It really depends on what the interview was for. Such a question could quickly identify people with a deeper understanding of JavaScript internals, and/or those who are familiar with writing JavaScript for environments where `window` is just another variable. There are a reasonable number of such environments. If all the person is going to be doing is writing vanilla JavaScript code for web pages, then, yeah, it is not that good of a question. On the other hand, the job may be to write code where this understanding *matters*.

Comment: @Makyen it's reasonable interview discussion topic. As a single-shot, 'gotcha' question, it's garbage.

Comment: @pvg, "single-shot, 'gotcha' question"s are almost always inherently garbage, just by their intent to be such questions. We can have no knowledge if this was, in this case, because the OP has not provided enough context about the job and the interview for us to make a determination.

Comment: @pvg, With respect to this specific topic, I've answered many questions on SO where the primary, or at least secondary, problem was that the OP did not understand that `window` was just another variable in the scope/context for which they were writing code. *If the job was specifically for writing code for such an environment*, I can certainly see myself asking something similar in an interview. As you mentioned, it would be as part of a discussion, not intended as a "gotcha", but could be part of gauging where the interviewee is with respect to their understanding of that environment.

Answer (score 3):

There is no difference between `console.log` and `window.console.log`.
Have a check on [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/console). They clearly quote -

> The Console object can be accessed from any global object, Window on
>   browsing scopes, WorkerGlobalScope, and its specific variants in
>   workers via property console. It's exposed as `Window.console`, and
>   can be referenced as simply `console`.

---

Adding to this, the question may have also been-

**What's the difference between `console.log` and `window.console`.**

The answer for this would be-

`console.log` is used for logging(as you know).

`window.console` checks if the console is available(`truthy` value) so that we can log next.(in case of mobile browsers, they don't support debugger/console)

Common pattern in code for this is-

`window.console && console.log(open_date);`

Which is basically short code for -

```
if( window.console ) {
    console.log( open_date );
}
```